# Python - function that returns one string that characters from the the other string are removed

Tags: python, string, replace

```
"""Return a copy of str1 with characters from str2 removed.

filter_string(string, string) -> string
"""

for a in str1:
    if a in str2:
      str1.replace(a,"")

return str1
```

Am i close?

str1 and str2 contain variable strings

so far my output is 21 oramrfrrdonRsmsov creea  h tite twrch

desired output is 21mdnRmvhiwh

Comment: As a side note, you could just use this instead: `str1 = str1.translate(None, str2)`

Comment: boom absolutely legend ^ good karma to you sir.

Comment: In Python 3: `str1 = re.sub('[%s]' % re.escape(str2), '', str1)` (ignoring issues with characters that consist of several Unicode codepoints).

Answer (score 5):

Your function can be written quite simply with the [`str.translate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method:

```
str1 = str1.translate(None, str2)
```

This removes all the characters in `str2` from `str1`.

For example:

```
>>> 'Hello, world!'.translate(None, 'lewf!')
Ho, ord
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehensions:

```
>>> str1 = "HelloWorld"
>>> str2 = "World"
>>> "".join([i for i in str1 if i not in str2])
'He'
>>>
```